# How can I combine models in tensorflow for a combined graph such that they follow an alternating order?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I wish to combine multiple resnet models into one model.

Specifically, if I have mod_1_inputs, mod_1_outputs and mod_2_inputs, mod_2_outputs, which are made using the same model just two different instances, how can I use these to make the order of variables follow a sequential alternating pattern?

In other words if I have x, y for a single model how can I double each layer, such that the model is two models in one? Where the two models do not share any layers.

e.g.

- Layer 1: Input 1 ( is x1)
- Layer 2: Input 2 (is x2)
- Layer 3: conv2d_1 (resulting from only input 1)
- Layer 4: conv2d_2 (resulting from only input 2),
- ...
- Layer N-1: Output 1 (resulting from only the layers from input 1, is y1)
- Layer N: Output 2 (resulting from only the layers from output 2, is y2)

I have tried using Model(inputs=[x], outputs=[y]), where x= x1 and x2 and y= y1 and y2 but this doesn't seem to work as the order of weights and biases don't follow the pattern mentioned above.

I am planning on using this combined model to access the weights and biases of each layer, so I need the layers to alternate between models so it will have the same accessible parameters.

Comment: Is this questions related to this other one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66726422/valueerror-you-called-set-weightsweights-on-layer-batch-normalization-20

Comment: Maybe you can tell us where this issue is coming from, we have several persons asking exactly the same (and in all three questions, the issue makes no sense).

Comment: Because weights and biases don't have a predefined order, order in what precisely?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy The weights and biases do have an order. When using a custom optimizer they are accessible through the grads_and_vars variable. My question is specifically how to combine two models...? I'm not sure why you're discussing weights to this extent. If the models can be combined in the structure mentioned, then the weights should follow that "order" anyway.

Comment: Because in your question you mention order of weights and biases, and that order is arbitrary, why do you need such specific order and how does this relate to any custom optimzer?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I am not asking for an explanation on the order of weights and biases. I only want to know how to combine models. If I remove that minuscule section from the post, does that help you narrow down my question :)? I have looked at other posts on combing models and I haven't necessarily found anything useful.

Comment: No, it does not really help, because as you have in your question, Model(inputs=[x], outputs=[y]), is the actual solution, but you disqualify it because of this weights and biases order. So of course people are going to ask about it. Specially as it makes no sense to me.

Comment: To me it sounds that you don't really need to combine the models, just put the layers in an array in the order you want.